# Apache Druid on Digital Ocean Kubernetes, receiving `Access Denied` when attempting `mkdir /var/druid`

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, druid

As the title indicates. I'm attempting to run Apache Druid on Kubernetes hosted on Digital Ocean. Locally I've run this exact configuration on Minikube and had it work fine, but when I switch the cluster to Digital Ocean I get an Access Denied error on each pod when attempting to create `/var/druid`.

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: router
  labels:
    app: router
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8888
  selector:
    app: router
```

PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: router
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

And Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: router
spec:
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: druid
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: druid
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: router
          image: apache/druid:24.0.2
          args:
            - router
          env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: us-west-2
            - name: DRUID_LOG4J
              value: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Configuration status="WARN"><Appenders><Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"><PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c - %m%n"/></Console></Appenders><Loggers><Root level="info"><AppenderRef ref="Console"/></Root><Logger name="org.apache.druid.jetty.RequestLog" additivity="false" level="DEBUG"><AppenderRef ref="Console"/></Logger></Loggers></Configuration>
            - name: DRUID_SINGLE_NODE_CONF
              value: micro-quickstart
            - name: druid_coordinator_balancer_strategy
              value: cachingCost
            - name: druid_emitter_logging_logLevel
              value: debug
            - name: druid_extensions_loadList
              value: '["druid-histogram", "druid-datasketches", "druid-lookups-cached-global", "postgresql-metadata-storage", "druid-multi-stage-query", "druid-s3-extensions", "druid-parquet-extensions"]'
            - name: druid_indexer_fork_property_druid_processing_buffer_sizeBytes
              value: 256MiB
            - name: druid_indexer_logs_directory
              value: /opt/shared/indexing-logs
            - name: druid_indexer_logs_type
              value: file
            - name: druid_indexer_runner_javaOptsArray
              value: '["-server", "-Xmx1g", "-Xms1g", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g", "-Duser.timezone=UTC", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager", "-Daws.region=us-west-2"]'
            - name: druid_metadata_storage_connector_connectURI
              value: jdbc:postgresql://postgres.druid.svc.cluster.local:5432/druid
            - name: druid_metadata_storage_connector_password
              value: FoolishPassword
            - name: druid_metadata_storage_connector_user
              value: druid
            - name: druid_metadata_storage_host
            - name: druid_metadata_storage_type
              value: postgresql
            - name: druid_processing_numMergeBuffers
              value: "2"
            - name: druid_processing_numThreads
              value: "2"
            - name: druid_storage_storageDirectory
              value: /opt/shared/segments
            - name: druid_storage_type
              value: local
            - name: druid_zk_service_host
              value: zk-cs.druid.svc.cluster.local
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8888
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/druid/var
              name: router
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: router
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: router
```

I am very new to Druid and Kubernetes, so I'm sure some of this isn't correct, but the scope of this work is literally just getting the configuration to work as it did locally, on DO. Googling suggests something about the Druid version being incorrect - lots of questions about Docker Compose. None of this seems very helpful as it *did* work on Minikube and the version hasn't changed.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a complete druid deployment. Have you tried the helm chart @ (https://github.com/apache/druid/tree/master/helm/druid). This doc (https://imply.io/blog/apache-druid-for-preppers/) might also help you in setting up deep storage to something other than "local" which will not work across pods.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC micro quickstart uses the local deep storage which does not work on kube solutions unless you have an NFS. You might want to configure deep storage  https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/cluster.html#deep-storage

Your druid version seems correct to me.